# hh:mm:ss format causing IF statement to return False

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, time

The following IF statement will not return true. I have tried it a s a formula also and the problem seems to be the hh:mm:ss formatting. Although the cell value in column F reads as "00:15:00" it will never return true such that cell value in G becomes "Auto close".

As always any help greatly appreciated.

```
    Columns("F").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    If Range("F" & i).Value = "00:15:00" Then Range("G" & i).Value = "Auto close"
```

Comment: Try `If Format(Range("F" & i).Value, "hh:mm:ss") = "00:15:00" Then`

Comment: time is stored as fractions of a day, so 15 minutes will be 0.0104166666...   15/1440

Comment: @SeanC You are certainly correct. But in some cases I seem to remember that such comparisons yield incorrect results. Maybe it was because of rounding or something. Can't remember. Anyway, that's when I switched over to using `TimeSerial(0,15,0)` instead.

Comment: Thank you, gizlmo that worked perfectly. I don't understand the solution fully though...

Comment: To explain, it's because the line `Columns("F").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"` is only changing the format of the cells in the range, not the format of the value. So even if the cell shows the value of `00:15:00` in the worksheet, when you compare it to `00:15:00` in VBA it will return `FALSE` because it's actually comparing the `Long` of `1.04166666666667E-02` to the string you have specified of `"00:15:00"`.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks v much

Comment: @Jordan Kindly share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. | Alternatively, the question owner may do so too.. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the line `Columns("F").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"` is only changing the format of the cells in the range, not the format of the value. So even if the cell shows the value of `00:15:00` in the worksheet, when you compare it to `00:15:00` in VBA it will return `FALSE` because it's actually comparing the `Long` of `1.04166666666667E-02` to the string you have specified of `"00:15:00"`.